# WHERE in sub subselect MySQL

Tags: mysql, subquery, where-clause

table "plan"

> ```
> id   name
> 1     abc
> 2     def
> 3     ghi
> ```

table "schedule"

> ```
> id     fk_store     fk_plan
> 1         4            1
> 2         4            1
> 3         4            1
> 4         6            1
> 5         6            1
> 6         5            3
> 7         7            3
> 8         7            3
> 9         12           1
> ```

this is my query:

```
SELECT plan.id as id, name, 
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(cnt) cnt FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) cnt 
FROM schedule WHERE fk_plan = plan.id GROUP BY fk_store) q) as schedule_count  
FROM plan LEFT JOIN schedule ON plan.id = schedule.fk_plan GROUP BY plan.id
```

I am expecting this result (for example in array):

```
 [0] = array(
    ['id'] = 1,
    ['name'] = 'abc',
    ['schedule_count'] = '3, 2, 1'
 ),

 [1] = array(
    ['id'] = 2,
    ['name'] = 'def',     
    ['schedule_count'] = ''
),

 [2] = array(
    ['id'] = 3,
    ['name'] = 'ghi',     
    ['schedule_count'] = '2,1'
),
```

Unfortunately i got an error that column plan.id in WHERE clause is undefined. When i dont use WHERE the result 'schedule_count' is '3, 2, 2, 1, 1' in every array. I found many similar solutions but i was not able to fix it.

I hope my question is clear. Thank you in advance.

Comment: plan.id actually doesn't exist where you call it as it would if you were using a join (which I couldn't tell if it's possible in your situation)

Comment: @Bartdude yes now I know it does not exist. But everything is possible so I expect this has a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
    SELECT  plan.id, name ,  GROUP_CONCAT(cnt)  AS schedule_count
    FROM plan left join (select fk_plan, count(fk_store) as cnt from schedule 
                         GROUP BY fk_store)t
              ON t.fk_plan  = plan.id                                 
    GROUP BY plan.id
```

[**DEMO IN FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d475a/28)

- If you to show the 0 instead of `(null)` then replace the above GROUP_CONCAT by this

  ```
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(cnt is null , 0 , cnt))
  ```

Comment: Your solution is absolutely perfect. But this is just part (subquery) of my complex query, and I've got an error about subquery is returning more than 1 row :(

Comment: @mesnicka you welcome :) , nice you got what you want . good luck! :)

Comment: yeah! Now my task is totally finished. Thanks to you. My weekend is going to be longer. I owe you a beer, man :)

Answer (score 0):

Using joins:-

```
SELECT plan.id as id, name, GROUP_CONCAT(PlanCnt)
FROM plan
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT fk_plan, COUNT(DISTINCT fk_store) AS PlanCnt FROM schedule GROUP BY fk_plan) Sub1
ON plan.id = Sub1.fk_plan
GROUP BY plan.id as id, plan.name
```